# Change several ARRAY into new ARRAYS

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I would like to know how to change the contents from several ARRAYS into new ARRAYS.
I have this 3 vars with a ARRAY each, lets say the first var is `$number` and it has this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 9
)
```

The second var is `$item` and it has this:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => house
        [1] => car
        [2] => bike
    )
```

And the third is `$color` and it has this:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => red
        [1] => white
        [2] => black
    )
```

How can I change the contents and create new arrays like this:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => house
        [2] => red
    )

Array
    (
        [0] => 3
        [1] => car
        [2] => white
    )

Array
    (
        [0] => 9
        [1] => bike
        [2] => black
    )
```

Comment: `array_merge()` probably..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a callback function with [array_map()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) that returns each value together:

```
$result = array();
function merge_arrays($a,$b,$c){
    return array($a,$b,$c); 
}
$result = array_map("merge_arrays",$number,$item,$color);
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/144125)**

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
<?php
$number = [1,3,9];
$item = ['house','car','bike'];
$color = ['red','white','black'];
$res = array_map(null, $number, $item, $color);
print_r($res);
?>
```

which will output a single array of arrays that you want:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => house
            [2] => red
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => car
            [2] => white
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [1] => bike
            [2] => black
        )

)
```